# I want this photo to rotate with a touch

Tags: java, android

I have looked at this question: Moving an Image in circular motion based on touch events in android But it only tells me how to move the image along a circle, not rotate it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this code to rotate your image hope that's png or some vector.

```
    private fun rotateLoadingAnimation() {
    val rotate = RotateAnimation(0f,
            180f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f)
    rotate.duration = 5000
    rotate.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    ivRotating.startAnimation(rotate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `clockwise` rotate animation to achieve this form of rotation in `res/anim/clockwiseanim.xml` put this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```